# script languages on windows mobile - something similar to python @ nokia s60

Tags: python, windows-mobile, mobile

I try to find something similar to nokia's **python for windows mobile** based devices - a script interpreter [in this case also able to create standalone apps] with easy access to all phone interfaces - ability to make a phone call, send SMS, make a photo, send a file over GPRS, etc...

While there is 2.5 **pythonce** available for windows mobile it is pure python interpreter and what I look for are all those "libraries" that nokia's python has like "import camera", "import messaging", ability to control the phone programatically. Also the bluetooth console of nokia python is great.

I do not want to use .NET CF as even there (AFAIK) to control camera you need to use some indirect methods (for example: http://blogs.msdn.com/marcpe/archive/2006/03/03/542941.aspx).

Appreciate any help you can provide, thanks in advance.

I hope there is something I was unable to locate via google.

Comment: Why isn't the CameraCaptureDialog class sufficient for your picture taking needs? It's true that to do low-level camera control you have to dig into the weeds, but you don't have to do that in order to just take a picture.

Comment: camera capture was just an example, also CameraCaptureDialog does require user input to make a photo so its not possible to make an automated photo every x secs, do some manipulation/checks on the image and take some action according to content.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if this is an opportunity for you to develop some C extension modules for the PythonCE project.

Comment: any guidance on C extension programming for pythonCE you can give? most probably I will not succeed but a starting point would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [Mortscript](http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=download&action=list&category=18). a widely used scripting for Windows Mobile. Not sure if it can access all the phones functions. I believe there is [TCL](http://www.kocjan.org/tclmentor/1-tcl/17-tcl-on-windows-mobile-introduction.html) for Windows Mobile as well.

Comment: thanks for help - I have not checked them before. 
Unfortunately: 

- I checked Mortscript manual - camera not mentioned, sms mentioned twice but in a registry editing context. 
Also - etcl and sms search does not give any link at google that seems interesting :(

Answer (score 0):

IronPython?